# PHP - how to dispaly a result based on a drop-down menu

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, seo

Working on google pagerank where i insert a keyword and the script returns urls with this keyword.the pagerank and alexa traffic is also returned

here's my form..

```
<form method = "post" action = "post.php">
    <input class="enter_key_word" type = "text" name = "key" placeholder = "Enter key words..." />
    <select class="drop-down">
        <option value = "type"> Set page rank </option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

    <select class="dropdown3">
        <option value = "type"> How many google pages to check </option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>   

<input class="submit_button" type = "submit" value = "Search" name = "submit" />
</form>
```

Here's the code which the form submits to..

```
include("alexa.php");
$newGoogleRankChecker = new GoogleRankChecker();
$key = $_POST['key'];
$newquery = $key;
$useproxies = 'TRUE_OR_FALSE';
$arrayproxies = 'ARRAY_PROXIES';
$googledata = $newGoogleRankChecker->find($newquery, $useproxies, $arrayproxies);
```

And here's the script 'alexa.php' that displays the url given a keyword from the above form plus the pagerank and alexa traffic..

```
if(!class_exists('GoogleRankChecker'))
{
class GoogleRankChecker
    {
        public $start;
        public $end;

        public function __construct($start=1, $end=2)
        {
            $this->start    = $start;
            $this->end      = $end;
        }

        public function find($keyword, $useproxie, $proxies)
        {   
            for($start = ($this->start-1)*10; $start <= $this->end*10; $start += 10)
            {
                $ua = array(
                    0   => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36',
                    10  => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0',
                    20  => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1'
                );




                    //var_dump($options);exit;
                //}

                    $options = array(
                        "http"      => array(
                            "method"    => "GET",
                            "header"    => "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                                "Cookie: biztech=indonesia\r\n" . 
                                "User-Agent: ".$ua[$start])
                    );




                $keyword        = str_replace(" ", "+", trim($keyword));
                $url            = "https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=$keyword&start=$start&num=0";
                $context        = stream_context_create($options);



                //var_dump($url);exit;
                if($this->_isCurl())
                {
                    $data   = $this->_curl($url, $useproxie, @$arrayproxies);
                }
                else
                {
                    $data   = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

                }
                //echo htmlentities($data);exit;
                if(is_array($data)) 
                {
                    $errmsg     = $data['errmsg'];
                    $results    = array("rank" => "zerox", "url" => $errmsg);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(strpos($data, "To continue, please type the characters below") !== FALSE || $data == FALSE || strpos($data, "We're sorry") !== FALSE)
                    {
                        $results    = array("rank" => "zero", "url" => "");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $flag   = false;
                        $j      = -1;
                        $i      = 1;

                        while( ($j = stripos($data,'<cite class="vurls">',$j+1)) !== false )
                        {
                            $k          = stripos($data,"</cite>",$j);
                            $link       = strip_tags(substr($data,$j,$k-$j));
                            $url = $link;


                            $ch = curl_init();
// 2. set the options, including the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://tools.digitalpoint.com/pagerank?url=$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// 3. execute and fetch the resulting HTML output
$output = curl_exec($ch);
// 4. free up the curl handle
curl_close($ch);

preg_match('/<dd style="font-weight:bold">(.*)<\/dd>/i', $output, $title);
$pagerank = $title[1];
// $pagerank = page rank

// get alexa rank

$ch = curl_init();
// 2. set the options, including the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// 3. execute and fetch the resulting HTML output
$output = curl_exec($ch);
// 4. free up the curl handle
curl_close($ch);
preg_match('/<REACH RANK="(.*)"/i', $output, $atid);
$alexarank = $atid[1];
//echo $alexarank;

echo "URL - <a href = 'http://$url'> $url </a>, PAGERANK - $pagerank, TRAFFIC(Unique Visitors) - $alexarank <br />";

                        }

                        if ($flag) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $sleep = rand(20,25);
                sleep($sleep);

                if($this->_isCurl() === false)
                {
                    return $results;
                }
            }

            if($this->_isCurl())
            {
                return $results;
            }
        }

    private function _isCurl()
        {
            return function_exists("curl_version");
        }

        private function _curl($url, $useproxie, $arrayproxies)
        {           
            $ch = curl_init($url); 

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
            if($useproxie)
            {
                if(!empty($arrayproxies))
                {
                    foreach($arrayproxies as $param => $val)
                    {   
                        curl_setopt($ch, $param, $val);
                    }
                }
            }
            $content    = curl_exec($ch);
            $errno      = curl_errno($ch);
            $error      = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            if($errno == 0)
            {
                return $content;
            }
            else
            {
                return array("errno" => $errno, "errmsg" => $error);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

here's an example of output displayed when i use a keyword like 'form'

```
URL - www.form.net.au/ , PAGERANK - 5, TRAFFIC(Unique Visitors) - 2253913
```

i have two questions:

1. how i can specify the pagerank in the above drop-down-menu so that the result will only return urls with ONLY the specified pagerank in the drop-down-menu e.g. if i'm to set the pagerank as 2 in the drop down menu, only urls with a page rank of 2 will be returned
2. is there like a predefined method for which i can specify from which google pages the result is to be returned??